# ApexCharts - Updating custom variable, array values on runtime

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I want to update graph on runtime.
I have 2 custom variable arrays in my code (data_action and data_alt) which I am trying to update. But, it's not working. All predefined variables, arrays are updated without any problem.

In example below, on clicking "Update Graph" button, graph data and x-axis labels are updated. But, tooltip on each data point is not updated.
Please advise.

Thanks,
Sandeep

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #chart {
      max-width: 950px;
      border:1px solid #367ee9;
    }

    #chart .chart-tooltip {
        padding:10px;
        font-family:tahoma,Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        color:#000000;
    }
  </style>

 </head>
 <body>

<div id="imgDiv" style="display:none;"><img id="imgElem"></img></div>

<div id="chart"></div>

<br />
<center><input type="button" value="Update Graph" onclick="fnUpdGraph()" /></center>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts'></script>
  <script>
        var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Denied Charges ($)',
          data: [33111, 27510, 27377, 14947, 4312, 7279, 70988, 2903, 29575, 65, 9861, 3416],
          data_action: ["dot1_action", "dot2_action", "dot3_action", "dot4_action", "dot5_action", "dot6_action", "dot7_action", "dot8_action", "dot9_action", "dot10_action", "dot11_action", "dot12_action"],
          data_alt: ["dot1_alt", "dot2_alt", "dot3_alt", "dot4_alt", "dot5_alt", "dot6_alt", "dot7_alt", "dot8_alt", "dot9_alt", "dot10_alt", "dot11_alt", "dot12_alt"]
        }],
        colors:['#367ee9'],
          chart: {
          height: 450,
          type: 'line',
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {
              bar_number = config.dataPointIndex;
              alert(chartContext.w.config.series[0].data_action[bar_number])
            },
            dataPointMouseEnter: function(event, chartContext, config) {
              event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            }
          },
          animations:{
            enabled: true,
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          formatter: function (val) {
            return "$" + val.toLocaleString();
          },
          offsetY: -20,
          style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#304758"]
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          width:2,
          curve: 'smooth',
        },
        markers:{
            size:5,
          },
        
        xaxis: {
          categories: ["Jul 19", "Aug 19", "Sep 19", "Oct 19", "Nov 19", "Dec 19", "Jan 20", "Feb 20", "Mar 20", "Apr 20", "May 20", "Jun 20"],
          position: 'top',
          axisBorder: {
            show: false
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false
          },
          crosshairs: {
            fill: {
              type: 'gradient',
              gradient: {
                colorFrom: '#367ee9',
                colorTo: '#367ee9',
                stops: [0, 100],
                opacityFrom: 0.4,
                opacityTo: 0.5,
              }
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: true
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
          axisBorder: {
            show: false
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false,
          },
          labels: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (val) {
              return "$" + val.toLocaleString();
            }
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Denied Charges ($)',
            style: {
                  color: '#000',
                  fontSize: '16px',
                  fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-title',
              },
          }
        
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            intersect:true,
            shared:false,
            custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
                return '<div class="chart-tooltip">' + w.config.series[0].data_alt[dataPointIndex] + '</div>'
              }
          },
        title: {
          text: 'Total Benefits Exceeded ($231,345) (Claim Date)',
          floating: true,
          offsetY: 430,
          align: 'center',
          style: {
            color: '#000'
          }
        }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();

        function fnUpdGraph(){
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();

            try{
                chart.updateOptions({
                    series: [{
                        data: [23111, 7410, 27977, 74447, 3412, 4979, 4944, 9403, 4575, 11645, 861, 74416],
                        data_alt: ["1dot1_alt", "1dot2_alt", "1dot3_alt", "1dot4_alt", "1dot5_alt", "1dot6_alt", "1dot7_alt", "1dot8_alt", "1dot9_alt", "1dot10_alt", "1dot11_alt", "1dot12_alt"]

                    }],
                    xaxis:{
                        categories: ["Jul 20", "Aug 20", "Sep 20", "Oct 20", "Nov 20", "Dec 20", "Jan 21", "Feb 21", "Mar 21", "Apr 21", "May 21", "Jun 21"]
                    }
                })
            }
            catch(e){
                alert(e)
            }
        }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I created "data_action" and "data_alt" as separate variables in "series". Since, these are not apex library variables, "updateOptions" did not update them. So, I had to add them inside "data".

Please see the solution below.

```js
function fnPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('printContent');
        var gr = document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML;
        gr = gr.substring(0,gr.indexOf('<div class="apexcharts-legend"'));
        var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
        if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
        oDoc.write("<html><head><title>Line Graph</title>");
        oDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
        oDoc.write("<center><br /><br />" + gr + "</center></body></html>");
        oDoc.close();       
    }
    catch(e){
        self.print();
    }
}

var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Denied Charges ($)',
          data: [
            {
                x:"Jul 19",
                y:33111,
                data_action:"dot1_action",
                data_alt:"dot1_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Aug 19",
                y:27510,
                data_action:"dot2_action",
                data_alt:"dot2_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Sep 19",
                y:27377,
                data_action:"dot3_action",
                data_alt:"dot3_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Oct 19",
                y:14947,
                data_action:"dot4_action",
                data_alt:"dot4_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Nov 19",
                y:4312,
                data_action:"dot5_action",
                data_alt:"dot5_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Dec 19",
                y:7279,
                data_action:"dot6_action",
                data_alt:"dot6_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Jan 20",
                y:70988,
                data_action:"dot7_action",
                data_alt:"dot7_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Feb 20",
                y:2903,
                data_action:"dot8_action",
                data_alt:"dot8_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Mar 20",
                y:29575,
                data_action:"dot9_action",
                data_alt:"dot9_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Apr 20",
                y:65,
                data_action:"dot10_action",
                data_alt:"dot10_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"May 20",
                y:9861,
                data_action:"dot11_action",
                data_alt:"dot11_alt"
            },
            {
                x:"Jun 20",
                y:3416,
                data_action:"dot12_action",
                data_alt:"dot12_alt"
            }
          ],
        }],
        colors:['#367ee9'],
          chart: {
          height: 450,
          type: 'line',
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {
              bar_number = config.dataPointIndex;
              alert(chartContext.w.config.series[0].data[bar_number].data_action)
            },
            dataPointMouseEnter: function(event, chartContext, config) {
              event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            },
          },
          animations:{
            enabled: true,
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          formatter: function (val) {
            return "$" + val.toLocaleString();
          },
          offsetY: -20,
          style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#304758"]
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          width:2,
          curve: 'smooth',
        },
        markers:{
            size:5,
          },
        
        xaxis: {
          type:'category',
          position: 'top',
          axisBorder: {
            show: false
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false
          },
          crosshairs: {
            fill: {
              type: 'gradient',
              gradient: {
                colorFrom: '#367ee9',
                colorTo: '#367ee9',
                stops: [0, 100],
                opacityFrom: 0.4,
                opacityTo: 0.5,
              }
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: true
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
          axisBorder: {
            show: false
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false,
          },
          labels: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (val) {
              return "$" + val.toLocaleString();
            }
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Denied Charges ($)',
            style: {
                  color: '#000',
                  fontSize: '16px',
                  fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-title',
              },
          }
        
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            intersect:true,
            shared:false,
            custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
                return '<div class="chart-tooltip">' + w.config.series[0].data[dataPointIndex].data_alt + '</div>'
              }
          },
        title: {
          text: 'Total Benefits Exceeded ($231,345) (Claim Date)',
          floating: true,
          offsetY: 430,
          align: 'center',
          style: {
            color: '#000',
          }
        }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();

        function fnUpdGraph(){

            try{
                chart.updateOptions({
                    series: [{
                        data: [
                            {
                                x:"Jul 20",
                                y:23111,
                                data_action:"dot1_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot1_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Aug 20",
                                y:7410,
                                data_action:"dot2_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot2_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Sep 20",
                                y:27977,
                                data_action:"dot3_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot3_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Oct 20",
                                y:74447,
                                data_action:"dot4_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot4_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Nov 20",
                                y:3412,
                                data_action:"dot5_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot5_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Dec 20",
                                y:4979,
                                data_action:"dot6_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot6_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Jan 21",
                                y:4944,
                                data_action:"dot7_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot7_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Feb 21",
                                y:9403,
                                data_action:"dot8_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot8_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Mar 21",
                                y:4575,
                                data_action:"dot9_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot9_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Apr 21",
                                y:11645,
                                data_action:"dot10_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot10_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"May 21",
                                y:861,
                                data_action:"dot11_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot11_alt (new)"
                            },
                            {
                                x:"Jun 21",
                                y:74416,
                                data_action:"dot12_action (new)",
                                data_alt:"dot12_alt (new)"
                            }
                        ]
                    }],
                });
            }
            catch(e){
                alert(e)
            }
        }
```

```css
#chart {
      max-width: 950px;
      border:1px solid #367ee9;
    }

    #chart .chart-tooltip {
        padding:10px;
        font-family:tahoma,Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        color:#000000;
    }
```

```html
<iframe id="printContent" name="printContent" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<div id="chart"></div>
<a href="javascript:fnPrint();">Print Graph</a>

<br />
<center><input type="button" value="Update Graph" onclick="fnUpdGraph()" /></center>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @JeremyCaney
I am kind of novice as far as posting answers/solutions on forums is concerned :) I'll keep your advice in mind now on.

I'll edit my answer but a quick question. I tried to post my code as a link to https://codepen.io/sandeept07/pen/jOLGMdY but the editor didn't allow it. I think, link to codepen is restrictred for some reason. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Huh, I’m not sure why, no? I’ve seen links to CodePen before, so that surprises me. That said, we definitely prefer for code to be included in the post itself, so that may be there to encourage this

Comment: @JeremyCaney please see this https://prnt.sc/1y0ci41